# python structure to raw string representation

Tags: python, hex

I want to know some thing, at this time I use python ctypes to make some wifi frame    structure and with lorcon2 I could send them across the Lan. I want to transform this structure in a byte string to get an unsigned hexadecimal représentation of this structure wich. I have seen for this purpose two functions which accomplish this. the ctypes.string_at and ctypes.wstring_at functions. I know that ctypes.wstring_at is for make an unicode string but ctypes.string_at is for ??? which kind of string could we get with it?? an ascII string?? or an hexadecimal string??
    suppose F() can transform a structure to an unsigned hexadecimal byte string:

> ```
>     class d(Strcuture):
>        _ fields _ = [("num",c_uint8),("char",c_char)]
>     s = d(num = 129,char  = 'c')
>     q = F(s)
> ```

if I make a print of "q", I want some thing like that:
'\xe1\x63'
0xe1 is 129 in hexadecimal
0x63 is 99 in hexadecimal
where 'c' is coded 99 in ascII
and again with all of that, I search another function to get the exact byte value of each   element in "q" suppose that this function is wx() so it could return this:
    129 if a write: wx(q[0])
    99 if I write: wx(q[1])

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Neither `F()` nor `wx()` is required.

```
class d(Structure):
  _fields_ = [("num",c_uint8),("char",c_char)]

  def __str__(self):
    return struct.pack('Bc', self.num, self.char)

  def __getitem__(self, ix):
    if ix == 0:
      return self.num
    if ix == 1:
      return ord(self.char)
    raise IndexError('structure index out of range')
```

Comment: it is the first time that I see __str__ and __getitem__, where can I learn about them? and what is the purpose of their use